# Changing Leaflet map according to input without redrawing

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm wondering how I can change Shiny and Leaflet to plot points according to the change in input without redrawing the whole map.

The code i'm using is:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Melbourne Urban Tree Visualisation"),
  leafletOutput("treedat"),
  uiOutput("precinct")
   #Giving an input name and listing out types to choose in the Shiny app
  )

server <- function(input, output){
  
  #td <- read.csv("treedata.csv", header = TRUE)
  
  #pal <- colorNumeric(
  #palette = "RdYlGn",
  #domain = td$LifeExpectencyValue
  #)
  
  output$precinct <- renderUI({
    
    choices <- as.character(unique(td$Precinct))  
    choices <- c('All', choices)
    selectInput(inputId = "precinct", label = "Precinct", choices = choices, selected = "CBD")
    
  })
  
  
  output$treedat <- renderLeaflet({
    #if(is.null(td)) return()
    ## get the choice from teh drop-down box
    PRECINCT = input$precinct
    
    ## supbset the data based on the choice
    if(PRECINCT != 'All'){
      td2 <- td[td$Precinct == PRECINCT, ]
    }else{
      td2 <- td
    }
    ## plot the subsetted ata
    td2 <- leafletProxy(td2) %>% addTiles(
      urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>') %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(radius= 5,
                       fillOpacity = 0.5, 
                       stroke = FALSE,
                       color=~pal(LifeExpectencyValue),
                       popup=paste("<b>", td$CommonName,"</b>", "<br>", 
                                   "<b>","Years Left:", "</b>", td$LifeExpectency, "<br>", 
                                   "<b>","Genus:","</b>", td$Genus)) %>% addLegend(pal = pal, 
                                                                      values = ~LifeExpectencyValue, 
                                                                      opacity = 1, 
                                                                      title = "Life Expectency")
    return(td2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The dataset used for the code is available at this link - [Melbourne Urban Forest Data](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Environment/Trees-with-species-and-dimensions-Urban-Forest-/fp38-wiyy)

There are a lot of points so I wouldn't want to re-draw each time the input is changed. The input is based on the "Precinct" column in the dataset. Any help here is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Use `leafletProxy`. There is a documentation under this [link](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html).

Comment: Hi, I tried leafletProxy but could not get it to work. The app wouldn't run at all? Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked at this more closely. Yes, you're using it wrong. I need some time to come up with a code sample (sadly, you did not provide a working example) to illustrate how to use the command.

Comment: Sorry about that! Take your time. No hurry. Thanks for offering to help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, there you go: `leafletProxy` is used to add layers to an existing leaflet map. The usage ist just like normal leaflet additions, but you don't need the rendering part, since the map is already rendered in your document.

The first and easiest part is to render the leaflet map on a basic level, that is tiles, legend, static drawings, everything that you want to do just once. This is your starting point. From there on, altering the map is only done by direct commands instead of re-renderings.

This map can now be accessed via its shiny output id. In out case, we had `leafletOutput("treedat")`, so if we want to address this map, we use `leafletProxy("treedat")`. We use the same syntax as in regular leaflet modifications. E.g. `leafletProxy("treedat") %>% addMarkers(lat = 1, lng = 1)` adds a marker to the existing map without re-rendering it.

Thus, every modification to the map can / has to happen from inside some `observe` statement and not from inside the `renderLeaflet`.  Note that every command is an addition to the original map, which is why I had to use `clearMarkers` in the example below.

Code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Melbourne Urban Tree Visualisation"),
  leafletOutput("treedat"),
  uiOutput("precinct")
   #Giving an input name and listing out types to choose in the Shiny app
  )

server <- function(input, output){

  td <- data.frame(
    LifeExpectencyValue = sample(20:100, 10), 
    Precinct = c(rep("CBD", 3), rep("ABC", 4), rep("XYZ", 3)),
    CommonName = sapply(1:10, function(x){paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")}),
    Genus = rep(c("m","f"), each = 5),
    lat = seq(5, 50, 5),
    lng = seq(2, 65, 7)
  )

  pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "RdYlGn", domain = td$LifeExpectencyValue)

  output$precinct <- renderUI({

    choices <- as.character(unique(td$Precinct))  
    choices <- c('All', choices)
    selectInput(inputId = "precinct", label = "Precinct", choices = choices, selected = "CBD")

  })


  output$treedat <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles(
        urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
      ) %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = td$LifeExpectencyValue, opacity = 1, title = "Life Expectency")

  })

  observeEvent(input$precinct, {

    #if(is.null(td)) return()
    ## get the choice from teh drop-down box
    PRECINCT = input$precinct

    ## supbset the data based on the choice
    if(PRECINCT != 'All'){
      td2 <- td[td$Precinct == PRECINCT, ]
    }else{
      td2 <- td
    }
    ## plot the subsetted ata
    leafletProxy("treedat") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lat = td2$lat, lng = td2$lng,
        radius= 5, fillOpacity = 0.5, stroke = FALSE, color=pal(td2$LifeExpectencyValue),
        popup = paste("<b>", td2$CommonName,"</b>", "<br>", 
          "<b>","Years Left:", "</b>", td2$LifeExpectency, "<br>", 
          "<b>","Genus:","</b>", td2$Genus))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thanks for this. I replaced your sample dataset with the original one but getting an "ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer" when trying to run the app.

Comment: Update: Fixed that! Parameters for my dataset was wrong. However, now when it runs, i get the world map view and have to zoom in quite a bit to get to Australia. Any idea on how i can fix this?

Comment: Use `setView` within the first initiation.

Comment: I tried this `leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles(
        urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
      ) %>% setView(lng = td$Longitude, lat = td$Latitude,  zoom = 4) %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = td$LifeExpectencyValue, opacity = 1, title = "Life Expectency")
    
  })`. But it did not work.

Comment: Update: Fixed it. But the map doesn't change according to the input. It still plots all. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: Fixed the above problem as well. How do I make Shiny point to the location that is changed with the input widget?

Comment: `setView` again on the proxy. Looks like you'll figure it out.

Comment: I tried using `setView` inside `observeEvent` but no luck. Hope you can help.

Comment: I just added `%>% setView(lat = mean(td2$lat), lng = mean(td2$lng), zoom = 3)` to the `leafletProxy` and it works.